# InstallShield 2012: Need to switch between sql scripts (sql server & oracle) based on property

Tags: installshield

The web applications I am installing can run against either a SQL Server or Oracle database. I need to be able to determine which database the user has (client is suggesting a property file) and then dynamically tell InstallShield whichSQL script to run, I know I can figure out how to determine which database is installed. My question is how do I configure the Feature/Component and tell InstallShield which script to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any Oracle servers available to me nor do I have the Oracle Instant Client.  If I did, it seems I'd use a Basic MSI project included in InstallShield to build an Oracle Instant Client MSI and add it to my installer as a setup prerequisite.  Kind of odd but I guess they couldn't get IBM / Oracle to play nicely.

So let's say I had all of that.  I'd create a Sql connection that supported both MS and ORA SQL and build it.  I'd run the installer with logging on and use the SQLLogin dialog to browse to a SQL instance and an Oracle Instance.

Then I'd look at that logfile and see if there's any evidence of the built-in InstallShield SQL custom actions setting a property that indicates the type and/or version of database server that it connected to.  Hopefully something will surface because I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Once I figured that out, I'd use the property in a conditional expression so that the SQL scripts only ran on the type of database server they were intended.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to use the file grep command to check the XML file the client has and then set a property value.  I was then able to configure the "Conditional Statement" for each SQL Script file to check the newly updated property.